# Solr doesn't index document's content

Tags: solr, indexing

I've a little problem with Sorl. 
I've indexed about 1400 documents by an xml file with the post.jar command. Within the xml file I placed some information like ID, TITLE and URL of the documents.

When I search a document, It finds nothing, but if I specified an attribute, ex. TITLE: IEEE, It finds the documents.

So I change, on schema.xml, the default field search from text to title. In this way it finds documents without specifying the attribute.

Why doesn't it find the content? Did I mess up the indexing by changing the xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Do a `q=*:*`. This fetches 10 (implicit default value for `rows`) documents with all fields and their values. Is all your data **indexed properly**?

Then do a `q=fieldx:val` with some known field and value. Do they show up in the results? Can you do more than string matches? If not, you need to choose **data types (and storage/indexing options)** in schema. Example: `string` allows only equality and prefix matches and `text` allows full text search.

Comment: I've tried both commands (`*:*` and `q=field: val`) and Solr show me the right result. ;)